# Remove words from UserDictionary?

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-softkeyboard, android-userdictionary

With [UserDictionary.Words](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html) and [`WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY) permission it's possible to **add** words to the user dictionary, but I don't see any way to **remove** words.

The motivation in this case is to add autocompletion suggests that are local to the app and remove them when exiting the app, but I can also imagine something like an app that automatically removed typos that were accidentally added.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to remove the exact word(s) using [`ContentResolver.delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#delete%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). Example:

```
private int deleteWord(String word) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(word)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return getContentResolver().delete(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
            UserDictionary.Words.WORD + "=?", new String[] { word });
}
```

And of course, need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
```

defined in the manifest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please help me in this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660006/issue-programatically-adding-word-for-word-prediction?