# How do i add Arabic words to the suggestions on top of my custom Arabic soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way to show Arabic words to the suggestions in my custom soft keyboard?
[This attached image clear you about what i want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BINc.jpg)

Comment: Programmatically? What's unique about Arabic?

Comment: Yes, Programmatically for android.

Comment: you have to develop your own keyboard. Keyboard is just another application.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660006/issue-programmatically-adding-word-for-word-prediction) help?

Comment: I have develop my own custom Arabic keyboard but struck in how to show suggestion words?

Comment: what about other languages? Only arabic is a problem?

Comment: There is only one language in my custom keyboard which is arabic.

Comment: so you just want to know how to show suggestions, not specific to any language? 1) edit the question. Not it says you have the problem specific with arabic. 2) use search to find how to show suggestions before you ask a question

Comment: Please see attached image.

Comment: @shmosel to undertand this keboard code need to become expert my self.